# Mule -Local Deployment issues on Mule using AnyPointStudio 6 on Windows 10

Tags: deployment, mule

I have an application which uses files in src/main/resources. When I do a maven clean install it generates a zip file which it puts in my local .m2 repository and in the the target folder. However, when I choose the Run As-> Run Configurations so that I can run the app locally, Mule chooses the wrong folder, which is in my workspace. That folder doesn't have the resources folder. How can I change the location of the file that Mule should use to run the local deployment, i.e. the embedded local server? The same application deploys correctly on windows 7 and with Anypointstudio 6.

The option Mule -> mavenize is grayed out in my IDE. However, when I select Run As-Run Configuration I can see Run As Maven Application. I choose that option and added the JVM arguments and tried to deploy. The build succeeded as shown:

INFO] Adding  as a lib
   [INFO] C:\Users\orbee\AnypointStudio\workspace\TestProject\mappings 
   does        not     exist, skipping
  [INFO] Building zip:
  C:\Users\orbee\AnypointStudio\workspace\TestProject\target\TestProject.zip
  [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------  -
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

The deployment failed however, with the error:

```
 Unable to copy project zip file to the embedded Mule instance. Project:   

[Mule Project] 
Name: TestProject - Domain: default
Source 'C:\Users\orbee\AnypointStudio\workspace\TestProject\target\
TestProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip' does not exist
```

It fails because it is trying to use the Snapshot zip whilst the zip that was actually built TestProject.zip and hence cannot find it. Is there a way to change the path to use the snapshot zip?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your project, Run As -> Mule Application with Maven. This will run the maven build, and then deploy it to the embedded server.

If the Run As menu has 'Mule Application' as the option instead of 'Mule Application with Maven', then Anypoint Studio has not determined that your project uses maven. In that case, right-click the project, Mule -> Mavenize or Mule -> Enable Support.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and comment!

Comment: Now it is looking for a snapshot build which is in my .m2 repository